# Encoding rules for the game of chess using finite state machine

Tags: algorithm, state-machine

I'm doing a self-educational research on finite state machines. And currently stumbled upon interesting but non-trivial task to accomplish. It is really hard to define state machine for the rules of game of chess.

Though the rules seem simple the game itself is hard to approach using FSM. I was thinking about encoding game state as a state of board, where each square is either empty or contains some piece. But it becomes hard to define transitions, because the transition should be aware of facts that concern the neighborhood of the subject cell. It is also hard to define transitions for cases like en-passant or castling, especially when castling is blocked by some other piece. The same way it is hard to define move limitations for pieces that are blocked by other pieces and are not capable to jump them, i.e. pawns, bishops, rooks, queens.

How would you approach this problem? Or maybe there are some extensions to FSM that I'm not aware of. I'm pretty sure that there are a lot of similar applications where FSM will be impractical to use. How would you deal with this problem in general case.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your approach each state would be a matrix of fields, where each field has a specific state, which is a composition of the color and the chess piece that is placed on it and chess pieces themselves are a composition of the color of the chess-piece and it's type (pawn, rook, etc.). So you can easily define rules by utilizing these matrices:

```
Example for pawn:
Initial state:
   C              D              E
5  (W , (X , ?))  (B , (P , B))  (W , (P , B))
4  (B , (P , W))  (W , (X , ?))  (B , (P , W))
```

Now we can evalute rules for moving the two white figures based on this rule:

A pawn can move straight forward, if it's not blocked by another figure, or it can beat the figure that is placed diagonally one block away from it. Building the transition-table for the above state with a white move next can be done in the following way:

```
S1->(a)X (just the standard way to define a transition)
a would be the figure, we want to move and S2 the resulting state
X are the reachable state.

a = Pawn at C4
we have two options evaluating the field:
    C5 is free, so we can move the pawn to that field
    D5 is held by a black pawn, so we can beat it and move to that field
a = Pawn at E4
    E5 not free, we can't move ahead
    D5 is held by a black pawn, which we can beat
```

Translating this into math shouldn't be too hard. The state transition-table for each state would include all possible moves for all figures. The resulting machine would be a NFA.

Another option would be to define transitions as a pair of the chess piece you want to move and where you want to move it. That'd allow you to construct a DFA.